# Vuetify 2 data table. Get row from given value

Tags: javascript, vuetify2

I'm using Vuetify 2 and I am trying to get the row values from a given value. I'm am using a barcode scanner as a keyboard input so I can change the packed quantity when the barcode is scanned. I am trying to use the Customer_barcode as the value to find the other data with in the same row.

The example date is received and stored in a object called "items:[]"
      `headers: [ { text: "Image", value: "image", sortable: false, }, { text: "Item", align: "start", value: "Line_Number" }, { text: "Part Number", value: "EI_Number" }, { text: "Qty ToPack", value: "Qty_Backordered" }, { text: "Qty Packed", value: "Qty_To_Ship" }, { text: "barcode", value: "Customer_barcode", align: " d-none" }, ]`

I am then able to get the customer barcode using a text-field that grabs the barcode with a method using this function below. Then I would like to add the quantity each time a barcode is scanned by getting the row data and modifying it. But I am unable to get the rows' data.

'handleBarcodeInput(event) {

```
  const scannedbarcode = event.target.value;
  console.log("Detected Barcode:", scannedbarcode);
//   console.log("Detected length:", scannedbarcode.length);
  if (this.scannedbarcode.length <= 8) {
    this.barcode = "";
    return this.barcode;
  }
  if (this.scannedbarcode !== null && this.scannedbarcode.length >= 9) {
    const item = this.items.find(item => items.Customer_barcode === scannedbarcode);<- doesn't work
    console.log(item); <- undefined

    // scannedbarcode = "";
    // return scannedbarcode;
  }
}'
```

I cannot seem to find the answer to this question anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by the following code which first gets the detected barcode, then it checks the length. After I use `.find()` to well obviously find the barcode in the array of items. Then parsing the int and changing it followed by a `$forceUpdate()` to the table to show the result. Also clearing the barcode to prep for the next scan.

```
updateItemProperties(event) {
  const scannedbarcode = event.target.value;
  console.log("Detected Barcode:", scannedbarcode);
  // Find the item with the matching customer barcode
  if (this.scannedbarcode.length <= 8) {
    this.barcode = "";
    return this.barcode;
  }

  if (this.scannedbarcode !== null && this.scannedbarcode.length >= 9) {
    const selectedItem = this.items.find(
      (item) => item.Customer_Barcode[0] === this.scannedbarcode
    );
    //   console.log('selected:',selectedItem);
    //   If the item is found, update the properties
    if (selectedItem) {
      if (parseInt(selectedItem.Qty_Backordered[0]) !== 0) {
        selectedItem.Qty_Backordered[0] =
          parseInt(selectedItem.Qty_Backordered[0]) - 1;
        selectedItem.Qty_To_Ship[0] =
          parseInt(selectedItem.Qty_To_Ship[0]) + 1;
        console.log("modified selected:", selectedItem);
        this.$forceUpdate();
        this.text = selectedItem.part_Number[0] + " Packed Qty 1";
        // console.log(this.text);
        this.snackbar = true;
      }
    }

    // Log the updated array for verification (you can remove this in production)

    this.barcode = "";
    items = this.items;
    // return this.barcode, this.items.length, this.items;
  }
}
```